# Removing a node in a circular doubly linked list

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I'm trying to write some code to remove a node from a circular doubly linked list. I've written the following function, which mostly works:

```
bool Circular::remove(int index)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return false;
    Node* current;
    current = head;
    if (index > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    else if (index < 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < abs(index); i++)
        {
            current = current->prev;
        }
    }
    if (current == head)
    {
        head = current->next;
    }
    else if (current == tail)
    {
        tail = current->prev;
    }
    current->prev->next = current->next;
    current->next->prev = current->prev;
    return true;
}
```

The only problem I have is that it won't remove the correct value when I pass the number 1 into the index number. Instead it always deletes the tail. If you think there's something wrong with my code somewhere else then I'll also look into it.

Comment: A good way to work through linked lists is pen and paper. Draw the nodes. Draw all of the links. One by one, and without having a link point at more that one place at a time, change the links to the desired configuration. Code the steps you had to take. Also invest some time in learning to use your system's debugger. Speeds up problem solving time when you can watch the program running line by line.

Comment: Can you give a full test case that shows the error?

Comment: Also, your `remove` method leaks memory; it drops the pointers but never deletes the node.

Comment: Even if it means more code in the question, you should probably also supply the function that adds items to the list; if adding something to the list goes wrong, deletion could likewise go wrong and the error could not be detected from the `remove` code alone.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. Mostly I used functions to remove the head...

```
Node* temp = head;
head = head->next;
head->prev = tail;
tail->next = head;
delete temp;
return true;
```

...and to remove the tail:

```
Node* temp = tail;
tail = tail->prev;
tail->next = head;
head->prev = tail;
delete temp;
return true;
```

Apparently just moving around the head and tail wasn't enough to actually delete those nodes.